# loss not chnging after 300 iteration

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, loss-function

my loss start high 0.65 then reduce until reach 0.01 and stop changing, when I check result still not good , should I wait , or what I have to do ?

my activation function is lrelu
last layer sigmoid
my loss function binary cross entropy

all layers fully connected layer

batch size =4

```
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 105, 'train aeu loss:', 0.6398013, 'total loss', 0.6398013)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 106, 'train aeu loss:', 0.63618463, 'total loss', 0.63618463)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 107, 'train aeu loss:', 0.6323359, 'total loss', 0.6323359)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 108, 'train aeu loss:', 0.628239, 'total loss', 0.628239)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 109, 'train aeu loss:', 0.6238803, 'total loss', 0.6238803)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 110, 'train aeu loss:', 0.61924565, 'total loss', 0.61924565)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 111, 'train aeu loss:', 0.6143209, 'total loss', 0.6143209)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 112, 'train aeu loss:', 0.609091, 'total loss', 0.609091)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 113, 'train aeu loss:', 0.60354114, 'total loss', 0.60354114)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 114, 'train aeu loss:', 0.597656, 'total loss', 0.597656)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 115, 'train aeu loss:', 0.5914216, 'total loss', 0.5914216)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 116, 'train aeu loss:', 0.58482814, 'total loss', 0.58482814)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 117, 'train aeu loss:', 0.5778549, 'total loss', 0.5778549)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 118, 'train aeu loss:', 0.5704867, 'total loss', 0.5704867)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 119, 'train aeu loss:', 0.5627097, 'total loss', 0.5627097)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 120, 'train aeu loss:', 0.5545108, 'total loss', 0.5545108)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 121, 'train aeu loss:', 0.54587483, 'total loss', 0.54587483)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 122, 'train aeu loss:', 0.5367902, 'total loss', 0.5367902)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 123, 'train aeu loss:', 0.5272466, 'total loss', 0.5272466)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 124, 'train aeu loss:', 0.51723653, 'total loss', 0.51723653)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 125, 'train aeu loss:', 0.5067488, 'total loss', 0.5067488)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 126, 'train aeu loss:', 0.49573797, 'total loss', 0.49573797)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 127, 'train aeu loss:', 0.48423475, 'total loss', 0.48423475)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 128, 'train aeu loss:', 0.47223735, 'total loss', 0.47223735)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 129, 'train aeu loss:', 0.45974857, 'total loss', 0.45974857)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 130, 'train aeu loss:', 0.44677627, 'total loss', 0.44677627)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 131, 'train aeu loss:', 0.43333283, 'total loss', 0.43333283)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 132, 'train aeu loss:', 0.41943556, 'total loss', 0.41943556)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 133, 'train aeu loss:', 0.40510648, 'total loss', 0.40510648)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 134, 'train aeu loss:', 0.3903734, 'total loss', 0.3903734)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 135, 'train aeu loss:', 0.37527022, 'total loss', 0.37527022)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 136, 'train aeu loss:', 0.35984012, 'total loss', 0.35984012)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 137, 'train aeu loss:', 0.34412184, 'total loss', 0.34412184)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 138, 'train aeu loss:', 0.32817447, 'total loss', 0.32817447)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 139, 'train aeu loss:', 0.3120531, 'total loss', 0.3120531)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 140, 'train aeu loss:', 0.29582202, 'total loss', 0.29582202)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 141, 'train aeu loss:', 0.27955088, 'total loss', 0.27955088)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 142, 'train aeu loss:', 0.2633138, 'total loss', 0.2633138)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 143, 'train aeu loss:', 0.24718845, 'total loss', 0.24718845)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 144, 'train aeu loss:', 0.23125465, 'total loss', 0.23125465)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 145, 'train aeu loss:', 0.2155931, 'total loss', 0.2155931)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 146, 'train aeu loss:', 0.20028353, 'total loss', 0.20028353)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 147, 'train aeu loss:', 0.18540315, 'total loss', 0.18540315)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 148, 'train aeu loss:', 0.17102464, 'total loss', 0.17102464)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 149, 'train aeu loss:', 0.15721451, 'total loss', 0.15721451)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 150, 'train aeu loss:', 0.14403132, 'total loss', 0.14403132)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 151, 'train aeu loss:', 0.13152426, 'total loss', 0.13152426)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 152, 'train aeu loss:', 0.11973214, 'total loss', 0.11973214)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 153, 'train aeu loss:', 0.10868255, 'total loss', 0.10868255)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 154, 'train aeu loss:', 0.09839133, 'total loss', 0.09839133)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 155, 'train aeu loss:', 0.08886323, 'total loss', 0.08886323)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 156, 'train aeu loss:', 0.08009201, 'total loss', 0.08009201)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 157, 'train aeu loss:', 0.07206154, 'total loss', 0.07206154)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 158, 'train aeu loss:', 0.06474711, 'total loss', 0.06474711)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 159, 'train aeu loss:', 0.058116734, 'total loss', 0.058116734)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 160, 'train aeu loss:', 0.052132864, 'total loss', 0.052132864)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 161, 'train aeu loss:', 0.046753947, 'total loss', 0.046753947)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 162, 'train aeu loss:', 0.04193723, 'total loss', 0.04193723)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 163, 'train aeu loss:', 0.03763741, 'total loss', 0.03763741)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 164, 'train aeu loss:', 0.03380844, 'total loss', 0.03380844)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 165, 'train aeu loss:', 0.030407183, 'total loss', 0.030407183)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 166, 'train aeu loss:', 0.027393982, 'total loss', 0.027393982)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 167, 'train aeu loss:', 0.024747191, 'total loss', 0.024747191)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 168, 'train aeu loss:', 0.022434363, 'total loss', 0.022434363)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 169, 'train aeu loss:', 0.020445904, 'total loss', 0.020445904)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 170, 'train aeu loss:', 0.0187451, 'total loss', 0.0187451)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 171, 'train aeu loss:', 0.01729209, 'total loss', 0.01729209)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 172, 'train aeu loss:', 0.01606659, 'total loss', 0.01606659)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 173, 'train aeu loss:', 0.015032028, 'total loss', 0.015032028)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 174, 'train aeu loss:', 0.014165167, 'total loss', 0.014165167)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 175, 'train aeu loss:', 0.013441812, 'total loss', 0.013441812)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 176, 'train aeu loss:', 0.012847084, 'total loss', 0.012847084)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 177, 'train aeu loss:', 0.0123621, 'total loss', 0.0123621)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 178, 'train aeu loss:', 0.011963224, 'total loss', 0.011963224)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 179, 'train aeu loss:', 0.011638624, 'total loss', 0.011638624)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 180, 'train aeu loss:', 0.0113756955, 'total loss', 0.0113756955)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 181, 'train aeu loss:', 0.011161308, 'total loss', 0.011161308)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 182, 'train aeu loss:', 0.01098865, 'total loss', 0.01098865)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 183, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010849173, 'total loss', 0.010849173)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 184, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010730466, 'total loss', 0.010730466)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 185, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010630407, 'total loss', 0.010630407)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 186, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010549757, 'total loss', 0.010549757)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 187, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010485613, 'total loss', 0.010485613)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 188, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010433215, 'total loss', 0.010433215)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 189, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010389576, 'total loss', 0.010389576)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 190, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010352248, 'total loss', 0.010352248)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 191, 'train aeu loss:', 0.0103185065, 'total loss', 0.0103185065)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 192, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010290246, 'total loss', 0.010290246)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 193, 'train aeu loss:', 0.01026703, 'total loss', 0.01026703)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 194, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010247082, 'total loss', 0.010247082)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 195, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010229151, 'total loss', 0.010229151)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 196, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010213042, 'total loss', 0.010213042)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 197, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010198735, 'total loss', 0.010198735)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 198, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010185955, 'total loss', 0.010185955)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 199, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010174904, 'total loss', 0.010174904)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 200, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010165406, 'total loss', 0.010165406)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 201, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010156921, 'total loss', 0.010156921)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 202, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010149105, 'total loss', 0.010149105)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 203, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010142249, 'total loss', 0.010142249)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 204, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010136051, 'total loss', 0.010136051)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 205, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010130281, 'total loss', 0.010130281)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 206, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010125015, 'total loss', 0.010125015)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 207, 'train aeu loss:', 0.0101200305, 'total loss', 0.0101200305)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 208, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010115301, 'total loss', 0.010115301)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 209, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010111166, 'total loss', 0.010111166)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 210, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010107304, 'total loss', 0.010107304)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 211, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010103617, 'total loss', 0.010103617)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 212, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010100296, 'total loss', 0.010100296)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 213, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010097368, 'total loss', 0.010097368)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 214, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010094685, 'total loss', 0.010094685)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 215, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010092108, 'total loss', 0.010092108)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 216, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010089636, 'total loss', 0.010089636)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 217, 'train aeu loss:', 0.0100874165, 'total loss', 0.0100874165)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 218, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010085274, 'total loss', 0.010085274)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 219, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010083204, 'total loss', 0.010083204)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 219, 'model saved!')
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 220, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010081198, 'total loss', 0.010081198)

('ep:', 0, 'i:', 238, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010060191, 'total loss', 0.010060191)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 239, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010059458, 'total loss', 0.010059458)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 240, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010058737, 'total loss', 0.010058737)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 241, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010058028, 'total loss', 0.010058028)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 242, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010057329, 'total loss', 0.010057329)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 243, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010056752, 'total loss', 0.010056752)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 244, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010056196, 'total loss', 0.010056196)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 245, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010055648, 'total loss', 0.010055648)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 246, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010055143, 'total loss', 0.010055143)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 247, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010054855, 'total loss', 0.010054855)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 248, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010054571, 'total loss', 0.010054571)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 249, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010054291, 'total loss', 0.010054291)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 250, 'train aeu loss:', 0.0100540165, 'total loss', 0.0100540165)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 251, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010053745, 'total loss', 0.010053745)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 252, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010053477, 'total loss', 0.010053477)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 253, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010053213, 'total loss', 0.010053213)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 254, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010052953, 'total loss', 0.010052953)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 255, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010052712, 'total loss', 0.010052712)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 256, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010052575, 'total loss', 0.010052575)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 257, 'train aeu loss:', 0.01005244, 'total loss', 0.01005244)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 258, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010052307, 'total loss', 0.010052307)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 259, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010052175, 'total loss', 0.010052175)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 260, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010052046, 'total loss', 0.010052046)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 261, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010051917, 'total loss', 0.010051917)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 262, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010051791, 'total loss', 0.010051791)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 263, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010051665, 'total loss', 0.010051665)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 264, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010051541, 'total loss', 0.010051541)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 265, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010051419, 'total loss', 0.010051419)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 266, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010051298, 'total loss', 0.010051298)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 267, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010051178, 'total loss', 0.010051178)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 268, 'train aeu loss:', 0.0100510605, 'total loss', 0.0100510605)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 269, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010050943, 'total loss', 0.010050943)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 270, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010050828, 'total loss', 0.010050828)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 271, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010050712, 'total loss', 0.010050712)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 272, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010050599, 'total loss', 0.010050599)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 273, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010050487, 'total loss', 0.010050487)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 274, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010050376, 'total loss', 0.010050376)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 275, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010050327, 'total loss', 0.010050327)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 276, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010050327, 'total loss', 0.010050327)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 277, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010050327, 'total loss', 0.010050327)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 278, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010050327, 'total loss', 0.010050327)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 279, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010050327, 'total loss', 0.010050327)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 280, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010050327, 'total loss', 0.010050327)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 281, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010050327, 'total loss', 0.010050327)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 282, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010050327, 'total loss', 0.010050327)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 283, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010050327, 'total loss', 0.010050327)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 284, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010050327, 'total loss', 0.010050327)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 285, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010050327, 'total loss', 0.010050327)
('ep:', 0, 'i:', 286, 'train aeu loss:', 0.010050327, 'total loss', 0.010050327)
```

should I reduce dataset I have 7000 sample to train with or increse learning rate?

Comment: Your model converges at loss 0.01. What's the problem with that?

Comment: problem result still not good? if I wait for more 1 epoch could result improve even loss value not changing ?

Comment: What do you mean, you checked the result and it is still not good? And no, it is unlikely waiting one more epoch would help, you seem to have converged.

Comment: Hardly. But don't focus on the loss, check the validation accuracy to see if your model improves or not

Comment: yup still not good

Comment: ok , my qs here , could accuracy change after epoch or so even loss still not changing ?